# Convert a openCV numpy array to Wand Image format

Tags: python, opencv, wand

How can I convert the numpy array got from binarize_image function and save that image. I am doing pre-processing on images. After converting the image into grayscale, I had used the turned them into binary image.

```
def binarize_image(img):
    ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(img, BINARY_THREHOLD, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return th1 # numpy.ndarray
```

Here i am saving the image

```
   img.format = 'jpeg'
img_buffer = np.asarray(bytearray(img.make_blob()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = binarize_image(img_buffer)

# ..... Code to convert the ndarray back to Wand Image format .......

img.save(filename=os.path.join(pdf_folder,image_folder,outputFileName))
```

Comment: You need to actually ask a question, All I can really see is some code

Comment: @GPPK I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing an *image file* with *pixel data* buffer. Simply decode the JPEG blob to a Mat, then encoded back.

```py
def binarize_image(img):
    mat = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(mat, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return cv2.imencode(".jpg", th1)

with Image(filename="wizard:") as img:
    img_buffer = np.asarray(bytearray(img.make_blob("JPEG")), dtype=np.uint8)
    ret, mat = binarize_image(img_buffer)
    with Image(blob=mat) as timg:
        timg.save(filename="output.jpg")
```

[image: output.jpg]

Although you could achieve the same task directly with [imagemagick](/questions/tagged/imagemagick) by using either [`Image.threshold`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.threshold), [`Image.contrast_stretch`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.contrast_stretch), [`Image.level`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.level), or [`Image.quantize`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.quantize) methods.